# Covering a set of intervals, continued

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, cg.comp-geom, scheduling

Peter Taylor and Tsuyoshi Ito solved a previous question that I posted:

[Covering a set of intervals](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4358/covering-a-set-of-intervals)

I have a slight variation on that question that I'd also like to ask. I'm not sure what the etiquette here is here but I'll post the original question + modification here (if that's discouraged then I sincerely apologize!)  The question posted was:

Is the following question in NP:  "Given a finite set of half-open intervals and integers $k$ and $L$, is there a subset of the intervals so the sum of their characteristic functions can be expressed as a sum of characteristic functions of $k$ intervals of length $L$?"

The problem is NP-complete via a reduction from the subset-sum problem.  My variation is:

> Does the complexity change if we
>   require that all of the given
>   intervals have length less than $L$?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine (and recommended) to do as you did. I'd also recommend that you post a link here in the original question, so readers visiting that question will know that there's followup discussion here.

Comment: It it great that you posted this as a separate question because this was what I was thinking when I saw your previous question.  Not that I know the answer to this version. :(

Comment: Slight correction... the previous version is NP-complete, not just in NP.  This version is clearly in NP, too; the question is whether it's still NP-complete.

Comment: By reduction from SUBSET-SUM problem we only know that this problem is binary NP-complete. Isn't this question about strong NP-completeness of the problem?

Comment: @Oleksandr: That is a closely related question, but not necessarily exactly the same.  Here each number (the coordinates of the endpoints of the given segments) can be large.  If the problem is strongly NP-complete, then the problem in this question is also NP-complete.